# Interface does not behave like an Object?

Tags: vb.net, object

I have a little problem with an interface.  A bunch of my classes implement the `ILayoutObject` interface.  A method declares a variable as `ILayoutObject` (defaulting it as Nothing) and then runs some code which decides which object it should be.  The problem is, the evaluation code runs in a method which receives the variable as a parameter and assigns an object to it.  With objects, this would be no problem.  The object would be affected by the changes in the method and everything would be OK.  Howeverm, when using an interface, the variable in the calling code remains `Nothing` and behaves like a normal variable.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to circumvent that?  Alas, due to code structure I am unable to use `ByRef` or functions :(

Here is some code:

```
Protected LayoutHandler As Dictionary(Of String, Action(Of Constants.OptionsEntryStructure, ILayoutElements)) = New Dictionary(Of String, Action(Of Constants.OptionsEntryStructure, ILayoutElements)) From
    {
    {Constants.KeyLayoutType, AddressOf KeyLayoutType}
    }

Sub MakeLayOuts
    Dim LayoutElement As ILayoutElements = Nothing 
    Dim Value = "SomeValues"
    Dim key = "Key"
    LayoutHandler(key)(Value, LayoutElement)
    ' LayoutElement remains nothing.....
End Sub

Protected Sub KeyLayoutType(elem As Constants.OptionsEntryStructure, Layout As ILayoutElements)
    Layout = New LayoutObject 'which would implement the interface
End Sub
```

Comment: `Begin Sub`...?  Pretty sure VB.net doesn't consider that valid syntax...

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the parameter as `ByRef` if you want to alter the object to which the variable in the calling code points to:

```
Protected Sub KeyLayoutType(elem As Constants.OptionsEntryStructure, ByRef Layout As ILayoutElements)
    Layout = New LayoutObject 'which would implement the interface
End Sub
```

This is true with any reference type (classes).  The fact that they are referenced with an interface makes no difference.

If you can't use `ByRef`, and you can't use a function to return the new object, then your only other real option would be to request a type of object which has the layout object as a property.  For instance:

```
Public Interface ILayoutElementContainer
    Public Property LayoutElement As ILayoutElements
End Interface

Protected Sub KeyLayoutType(elem As Constants.OptionsEntryStructure, Container As ILayoutElementContainer)
    Container.LayoutElement = New LayoutObject 'which would implement the interface
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this clashes with the Handler. This gist of the error message is a signature missmatch and I cannot figure out how to add a byref to the handler...

Comment: Oops.  Sorry, I read your question too quickly and missed the part where you said you couldn't use ByRef.  See my updated answer.

Comment: thx - Which won't work with my approach either :/ Simply because Container is also a different signature.
Seems I have to cobble up something...

Comment: Yeah, there's no other way to do what you are looking to do.  That's the purpose of the `ByRef` keyword.  I'm sure you could come up with an ugly work-around using global variables or class-level fields, but I would strongly recommend refactoring the existing code to make it possible for this to be a function which returns the object.

Comment: Indeed I have build such an ugly think - I have seen some suggestions how to build your own action delegate to avoid this problem, but I have no time :/